# ubuntu doesn't remember the gnome-tweaks keyboard layout switching configuration

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, gnome-tweaks

I've set Ubuntu to use CapsLock to change keyboard layout using gnome-teaks. This works fine, but every time I shut down the computer I have to configure this again. In gnome-tweaks the checkbox is marked, but I have to uncheck it or check it again (or check another option and uncheck it). How can I cancel that?

Thanks

---

Some information that might be useful
keyboard configuration

```
yotama9@computer:~$ cat /etc/default/keyboard 
XKBLAYOUT=us,il,gr
XKBVARIANT=alt-intl,,
BACKSPACE=guess
```

gstring capslock config (right after reboot)

```
yotama92@computer gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
['grp:caps_toggle']
```

Comment: Hi. I've added the output of the ``cat`` command. Yes, CapsLock reverts back to its regular function.

Comment: Hi @GunnarHjalmarsson added. TBH this seems correct to me.

Comment: Yeah, to me too. And you said that _Tweaks_ sees it (i.e. it's checked) when you open _Tweaks_. The question is why the desktop ignores it at login. If you are on Ubuntu 20.04, it might possibly be related to [bug #1899206](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1899206). You may want to add a comment on that bug report if you think it's related.

Comment: Thanks, I've reported that. The thread also suggests downgrading mutter and this solves the issue.

Comment: I have the same issue. Tweaks reads the configuration correctly, but I have to start it and change any setting for it to be applied to the desktop.

Comment: Upgrading to https://launchpad.net/%7Egunnarhj/+archive/ubuntu/mutter seems to have solved the issue, so it is indeed the bug mentioned in the comments above.

Answer (score 0):

Just summarizing the discussion in the comments above:

If you are on Ubuntu 20.04, it might possibly be related to [bug #1899206](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1899206).

A fix for the issue is currently published here:
https://launchpad.net/%7Egunnarhj/+archive/ubuntu/mutter